# Java Application Profiling and Testing

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, profiling

I am looking for the `Eclipse plugin` or the any other tool that help me to find Bottleneck in my web-application..
any-body help me to fix this...
Thanks in advance.

Comment: netbeans IDE ship with perfect profiling Tool.

Comment: "Bottleneck in my web-application" is quite generic. What is that you need, memory analysis, performance?

Comment: The answer even depends on the OS you use. I found that Mac OS X is not supported by all tool out there.

Comment: @RaviBhatt i need for Memory analysis and execution timing..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can recommend [JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html). It has an [eclipse plugin](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/ide-eclipse.html) that lets you profile all your run configuration from eclipse and gives also you source code navigation in eclipse. [This screen cast](http://blog.ej-technologies.com/2009/06/jprofilers-ide-integrations.html) shows you how to set up and use the IDE integration.

Disclaimer: My company develops JProfiler.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Java 5+ try [JVisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/). IIRC JVisualVM is included in Java SE distributions starting from Java 6.

Answer (score 0):

Try JMeter (since you want execution timings). There is a eclipse setup within eclipse. Have a look here http://people.apache.org/~mkostrze/jmeter-eclipse/index.html